# MVC asp.net PartialView causing No Parameterless constructor error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Having an issue with an MVC 2.0 application partial view that all of the sudden when accessed and stuff is actually in the ViewData, the dreaded No parameterless Constructor error. I Have followed the code as much as I can and I'm getting no where. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Interfaces;
    using CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Repository;
    using CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Entities;

    namespace CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Controllers
    {
        public class CatalystSearchController : Controller
        {
           // private SqlCatalystRepository _catalystItemRepository;
            private ICatalystRepository _catalystInterface;
            public int PageSize = 10; // Regulates size of page

        #region CONSTRUCTOR

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor which sets the passed repository to the local current 
        /// repository
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="catalystRepository">Interface repository for controller</param>
        public CatalystSearchController()
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region  DEFAULT VIEW


        public ViewResult List([DefaultValue("")] string manufactureName, [DefaultValue("")] string manufacturePartNumber, [DefaultValue("")] string description, [DefaultValue(1)] int page)
        {

            IQueryable<CatalystItem> query = null;
            CatalystFilter userFilter = new CatalystFilter();
            int totalItems = 0;

           // Be sure that the manufacture drop down has been selected
            if (manufactureName != "")
            {
                // Set up CatalystFilter
                userFilter.Manufacture = manufactureName;
               userFilter.DescriptionFilter = description;
                userFilter.ManufacturePartNumberFilter = manufacturePartNumber;

                // connection string for SQL
                string connString = "Data Source=se-cinet-dev;Initial Catalog=cinet;User ID=sa;Password=Carouse1";


                // Get interface
                _catalystInterface = new CatalystRepository(connString);


                // Collects data from SQL repository and updates private local copy
               // _catalystItemRepository = new SqlCatalystRepository(connString);

                // Fills with list of Catalystitems based on filter.
                query = _catalystInterface.GetCatalystItems(userFilter, page, PageSize);
                // query = _catalystItemRepository.GetItems(userFilter, page, PageSize);

                // Returns int of total items in list
                totalItems = _catalystInterface.GetTotalOfItems(userFilter);
                // totalItems = _catalystItemRepository.GetTotalOfItems(userFilter);

                // Set up view model for passing to View
                var viewModel = new CatalystModel
                {

                    catalystItems = query.ToList(),
                    catalystFilter = userFilter,

                    /* Pass Paging properties to model*/
                    PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                    {
                        CurrentPage = page,
                        ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                        TotalItems = totalItems

                    },
                    ManufactureName = manufactureName

                };

                // View Data to be passed to SearchView
                ViewData["catalystItems"] = viewModel;


                return View(viewModel);
            }

            else
            {
                var viewModel = new CatalystModel();
                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region SEARCH VIEW

        /// <summary>
        /// Partial View used to display results from controller
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"> model passed via ViewData from List View</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ViewResult SearchView(CatalystModel model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        #endregion

    }
}

listView:

    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Entities.CatalystModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.HtmlHelpers" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Interfaces" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div>
        <center>
            <strong>
                <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Please fill out required Fields") %></strong> 

                <h1>Catalyst Search Provider</h1>
            <hr />
            <%-- "Search","Catalyst" --%>
            <% 
                using (Html.BeginForm())
                { %>
            <table border="1">

               <tr>
                <td>Enter Description (optional):</td>
                <td>
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Description) %>
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>Enter Part Number (optional):</td>
                <td>
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ManufacturePartNumber) %>
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Choose Manufacture:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ManufactureName, Model.GetAllManufactures()) %>
                       <%--  <%: Html.DropDownList("ManufactureName", Model.GetAllManufactures(),"Choose Item")%> --%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <% } Html.EndForm();  %>
            <!-- RENDERS PARTIAL VIEW TO DISPLAY GRID WITH SEARCH RESULTS -->
            <% Html.RenderAction("SearchView", ViewData["catalystItems"]); %>
            <br />
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="pager">

       <% if (Model.PagingInfo != null)
          { %>
        <%: Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x, manufactureName = Model.catalystFilter.Manufacture, description = Model.catalystFilter.DescriptionFilter, manufacturePartNumber = Model.catalystFilter.ManufacturePartNumberFilter }))%>
        <% } %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>


SearchView:

    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Entities.CatalystModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.HtmlHelpers" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models" %>

 <div>
    <% if (Model.catalystItems != null)
       { %>
        <table class="CatalystTableSpacer">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Contract Price
                </td>
                <td>
                    Description
                </td>
                <td>
                    Manufacture Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Manufacture Part Number
                </td>
                <td>
                    MSRP Price
                </td>
                <td>
                    Quantity Available
                </td>

            </tr>
            <% foreach (var items in Model.catalystItems)
               {%>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%: items.ContractPrice%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: items.Description%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: items.ManufactureName%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: items.ManufacturePartNumber%>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <%: items.MSRPrice%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: items.QuantityAvailable%>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <% }
       }

                %>
            </table>

           </div>
```

CatalystModel

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Entities;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Repository;
using CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Interfaces;

namespace CINet.Areas.CatalystSearch.Models.Entities
{
    public class CatalystModel
    {

          #region PRIVATE FIELDS

        private string _connectionString = "Data Source=se-cinet-dev;Initial Catalog=cinet;User ID=sa;Password=Carouse1"; // connection string for SQL
        private ICatalystRepository _repository = null;

        #endregion
    #region PUBLIC PROPERTIES

    public IList<CatalystItem> catalystItems { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    public CatalystFilter catalystFilter { get; set; }
    public SelectList Manufactures { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ManufactureName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ManufacturePartNumber { get; set; }

    #endregion


    #region CONSTRUCTOR

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor instantiates SQL DB Connection
    /// </summary>
    public CatalystModel()
    {
        _repository = new CatalystRepository(_connectionString);
     //   Manufactures = GetAllManufactures();
    }



    #endregion

    #region PUBLIC GET LISTS

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns ALL Manufactures in Database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public SelectList GetAllManufactures()
    {
        SelectList manufactureNameSelectList;
        List<Manufacture> manufactureTempList = new List<Manufacture>();

        // Get List from DB
        manufactureTempList = _repository.GetManufactureList();

        // PUSH LIST INTO SELECT LIST
        manufactureNameSelectList = new SelectList(manufactureTempList, "ManufactureName", "ManufactureName");

        return manufactureNameSelectList;
    }



    #endregion

}
```

}

The error happens in the ListView calling the SearchView:

<% Html.RenderAction("SearchView", ViewData["catalystItems"]); %>

Any help??

Actual Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

No parameterless constructor defined for this object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Source Error: 


Line 53:             <!-- RENDERS PARTIAL VIEW TO DISPLAY GRID WITH SEARCH RESULTS -->
Line 54:           <%-- <% Html.RenderPartial("SearchView", ViewData["catalystItems"]); %>
Line 55:           --%> <% Html.RenderAction("SearchView", ViewData["catalystItems"]); %>
Line 56:             
Line 57:             <br />


Source File: c:\Users\gcoleman\Documents\Source Code\Sandbox\Jonathan Henk\MVC\CINet\CINet\Areas\CatalystSearch\Views\CatalystSearch\List.aspx    Line: 55 

Stack Trace: 


[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +403
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindSimpleModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult) +544
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +479
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +658
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +147
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +2504
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +548
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +475
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +830
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4() +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +141
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9() +44
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action) +113
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +124
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1072

[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.]
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +3058371
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +77
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +28
   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +766
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, Object routeValues) +65
   ASP.areas_catalystsearch_views_catalystsearch_list_aspx.__RenderContent1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Users\gcoleman\Documents\Source Code\Sandbox\Jonathan Henk\MVC\CINet\CINet\Areas\CatalystSearch\Views\CatalystSearch\List.aspx:55
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +109
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   ASP.views_shared_site_master.__Renderform1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Users\gcoleman\Documents\Source Code\Sandbox\Jonathan Henk\MVC\CINet\CINet\Views\Shared\Site.Master:26
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +109
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8820669
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +31
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +53
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +56
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3060




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `CatalystModel` class doesn't have a default constructor so the default model binder cannot instantiate it here:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ViewResult SearchView(CatalystModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

This being said having such a child controller action that you are invoking like this:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("SearchView", ViewData["catalystItems"]); %>
```

is totally useless and bring strictly no value.

Why don't you render the partial directly:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SearchView", ViewData["catalystItems"]); %>
```

You should also read the [Haacked blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) to better understand the differences between RenderAction and RenderPartial.

Or if you really (for some cryptic reason) have controller actions that take some models which do not have default constructors as action parameters you will need to write a custom model binder for this type and specify which of your custom constructors should be used to instantiate it and what values should be passed to it of course.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so fast here. I had read a while ago that RenderPartial was less used, but i will read that article to get a better uderstanding. As for, the constructor, isn't this what it's asking for with the Model?  /// <summary>
        /// Constructor instantiates SQL DB Connection
        /// </summary>
        public CatalystModel()
        {
            _repository = new CatalystRepository(_connectionString);
         //   Manufactures = GetAllManufactures();
        }

Comment: @user479323, I talked about the `CatalystModel` class which doesn't have a parameterless constructor. I really don't know what you are showing me in your comment.

Comment: Right but what I'm saying is that i do have a parameterless constructor... it least it seems that way. see above, i edited my post to include the CatalystModel class.??     #region CONSTRUCTOR      /// <summary>     /// Constructor instantiates SQL DB Connection     /// </summary>     public CatalystModel()     {         _repository = new CatalystRepository(_connectionString);      //   Manufactures = GetAllManufactures();     }

Comment: Also - the RenderPartial fixed the isue, but i would still like to understand why what did broke

Comment: ok... as much as i appreciate your response, attitude and being a jerk when I'm trying to learn is unnessesary, obviously there is something i am missing when you say parameterless constructor. With that said, can you please explain why public CatalystModel(){} is not a parameterless instructor? Thats what i have in my model clas, is that not what it is looking for? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user479323, you are correct. There is a parameterless constructor defined for this type. So maybe you could share for which type you get this exception? Maybe some of the sub types such as CatalystFilter, PaginInfo, CatalystItem that you are using over there? Normally the exception tells which type doesn't have a parameterless constructor, I suspect some of the types use in the CatalystModel hierarchy.

Comment: If u look at my above Class that I updated, there should be a CatalystModel parameterless constructor in the class

Comment: @user479323, yeah I see that. What about the CatalystFilter, PaginInfo, and CatalystItem classes? I can't see them. Do they have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: No not all of them do, that may be the problem, I thought that issue only covered the model, but i guess since the model accesses other stuff, that is probably it. i posted the error too if you see anything, let me know, otherwise no worries, i think I'm good. Thank you again for your help. i will be reading that article too!!

Comment: @user479323, now that you have posted the exception stacktrace it is clear that some of the objects involved in the `CatalystModel` type doesn't have a default constructor. Unfortunately the error message doesn't allow to know which one. It could be some type very deep in this hierarchy. By the way that's one of the reasons why you should always use view models as input/output to/from your controller actions instead of using your domain models. For each view that you are dealing with it is a good practice to define a specific view model and then map back and from from your domain entities.

Comment: ok... i will start to reconstruct my code in this manner.So if I understand you correctly, I should have a seperate Viewmodel for each View ( The Start View and then the Search Results) and then have everything that relates to the domain entities handled in the controller? I thought that models should be used across partial views?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("SearchView", new { model = ViewData["catalystItems"] }); %>
```